# All Windows console applications screen buffer size

Tags: windows, buffer, console-application

Is there a way to change default screen buffer size (count of scrollable lines before they become unavailable) for all console applications in Windows? Registry key or something. I don't want to set it for every console app I develop.

Regards,

Comment: You can do this easily through the properties of the console window. Are you asking how to do this through a program? I would discourage this, changing someone's global settings just to suit your own program is pure evil.

Comment: this is a superuser question, the answer is what mark said

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\
```

There is a bunch of keys in there you can adjust.

Answer (score 1):

See http://commandwindows.com/configure.htm or 
[How to change Screen buffer size in Windows Command Prompt from batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692673/how-to-change-screen-buffer-size-in-dos-command-prompt-from-batch-script)