# Telnet output overflow, not able to see complete output

Tags: cmd, telnet

I am working on simulator,the simulator connects to a telnet and outputs the printf's on to the telnet window. I tried increasing the buffers and everything in  the properties but output overflows. I am also not able to type anything on the telnet prompt. Is there any way to se my complete output on the telnet prompt??
[image]

[image]

As you can see i cannot see entries above (21....) in the telnet screen.I even cannot type anything in the telnet prompt.
Anything would help!!!

Comment: Could you show us a screenshot of the problem?

Comment: As requested @ rojo...

Answer (score 0):

I would've guessed that the input line was either covered by your taskbar or off the bottom of your display before I saw your screenshots.  I'm not sure whether the window height being maxed out has anything to do with the problem, but my answer is based on the possibility of it.  Try leaving the screen buffer size high but the window size closer to normal.

[image: console window layout settings]

If you've got Powershell installed, try this batch script to set your console window size and buffer before you telnet.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set width=80
set height=35
set buffer=9999

mode con: cols=%width% lines=%height%
powershell -command "&{$H=get-host;$W=$H.ui.rawui;$B=$W.buffersize;$B.width=%width%;$B.height=%buffer%;$W.buffersize=$B;}"
```

([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311924/))