# Windows console width in environment variable

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, console, cmd

How can I get the **current width** of the windows console in an environment variable within a batch file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I like the approach using the built-in `mode` command in Windows.
Try the following batch-file:

```
@echo off
for /F "usebackq tokens=2* delims=: " %%W in (`mode con ^| findstr Columns`) do set CONSOLE_WIDTH=%%W
echo Console is %CONSOLE_WIDTH% characters wide
```

Note that this will return the size of the console buffer, and not the size of the window (which is scrollable).

If you wanted the height of the windows console, you can replace `Columns` in the `findstr` expression with `Lines`.  Again, it will return the height of the buffer, not the window... I personally like to have a big buffer to allow scrolling back through history, so for me the Lines usually reports about 3000 :)

---

Just for fun, here's a version that doesn't use `findstr` to filter the output... in case (for some reason) you have a dislike of `findstr`:

```
@echo off
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2* delims=: " %%V in (`mode con`) do (
    if .%%V==.Columns (
        set CONSOLE_WIDTH=%%W
        goto done
    )
)
:done
echo Console is %CONSOLE_WIDTH% characters wide
```

Note, this was all tried in Windows XP SP3, in a number of different windows (including one executing FAR manager).

Comment: This approach crashes if the system is using any other language than english. Look at @user2475020 's answer if you want language independency.

Answer (score 5):

try this (language/locale/.net independent):

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "ConsoleWidth="
SET /A LINECOUNT=0
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,*" %%A IN ('mode con') DO (SET /A LINECOUNT=!LINECOUNT!+1&IF !LINECOUNT! EQU 4 SET ConsoleWidth=%%B)
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "LINECOUNT="
ECHO ConsoleWidth: %ConsoleWidth% characters
```

tested on Windows XP and Windows 7, both in Czech language

Answer (score 2):

Powershell's `(Get-Host).UI.RawUI.WindowSize` property sets or returns the dimensions of the current console window.  You can capture it with a `for` loop thusly:

```
for /f %%I in ('powershell ^(Get-Host^).UI.RawUI.WindowSize.width') do set width=%%I
```

Comment: This assumes powershell is installed though, which might not be the case for XP users.

Comment: +1, The powershell command can be as simple as `powershell (get-host).ui.rawui.windowsize.width`. Background info is available at http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/12/04/how-can-i-expand-the-width-of-the-windows-powershell-console.aspx

Comment: @AxelFontaine - I don't think there is a pure batch solution. The info is exposed via .NET, and as far as I know, Powershell is the only native scripting language that can access .NET. Unfortunately, you are correct, Powershell may not be available on an XP machine.

Comment: Here is a better reference from Microsoft: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156814.aspx. Buried within it states how PowerShell gains access to the properties via .NET

Comment: @AxelFontaine - challenge: accepted.  See my [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14981186/1683264).

Answer (score 1):

Alright, here's one that doesn't require powershell to be installed.  It composes, runs and deletes a .Net application to set a batch script variable.  :)

```
@echo off
setlocal
pushd "%windir%\microsoft.net\"
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('dir /s /b csc.exe') do (
    set csc=%%I
    goto next
)
:next
popd
echo using System;>width.cs
echo class Width {>>width.cs
echo public static void Main() {>>width.cs
echo string m1 = "{0}";>>width.cs
echo Console.WriteLine^(m1, Console.WindowWidth^); } }>>width.cs
"%csc%" /out:width.exe width.cs >NUL 2>NUL
for /f %%I in ('width.exe') do set width=%%I
del width.exe width.cs
echo %width%
```

Comment: This answer relies on having .Net installed, and doesn't check if `csc.exe` doesn't exist. That said, I approve of the extreme coding! Well done.

Comment: This works...but it's a little confusing because you used `.vb` for the source file extension, but your code is actually C#.

Comment: Ya, I started out writing it in vb but switched to c#.  I didn't feel like editing the file extensions but I'll go ahead and do it since someone noticed.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't get it in an environment variable, but it is stored in the registry so you can access it from your batch script.

There are answers here about how to change it:
[How to change Screen buffer size in Windows Command Prompt from batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692673/how-to-change-screen-buffer-size-in-dos-command-prompt-from-batch-script)

In a similar way you can use `reg.exe QUERY [key details]` rather than `reg.exe ADD [details]`.  See the [Technet documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978570.aspx) for `HKCU\Console` for details.

Comment: How does this work with multiple consoles and multiple widths? How can I know which key applies to my current console (as opposed to simply the default width for a new console)?

Comment: When I get to work I'll link to the technet article for `hkcu\console\windowsize`.  Also, I know there is a powershell-ish way of setting the current window dimensions and buffer size.  I'll see if I can find something similar to read the dimensions rather than set.

Comment: @rojo: there's already an answer from you on the question I linked to using a powershell method.

Answer (score 0):

For a one simple line:

```bat
for /f tokens^=2 %%w in ('mode con^|find "Col"')do set _width=%%~w"
```