# Covering text in batch files

Tags: batch-file

Is there a way to "cover text" so like this:
I echo out "Hello world" but now I want to have it say "Pie is good" so I need it to print over it.
I can not use cls because it flickers.

Edit:

I need to use lots of `echos` that I need it to start the text back at "0, 0,".

Comment: Short answer, no. You may have to live with the flickering.

Comment: There are various variants of `set /p` tricks to (probably) get what you want, have a look here: http://superuser.com/questions/82929/how-to-overwrite-the-same-line-in-command-output-from-batch-file

Comment: Take a look at jeb's post at http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=1344

Comment: Mmm is there a way to make the text start at 0 0? that is what I need. The stuff you guys linked does not work for me.

Comment: I posted working code below.

Answer (score 2):

This is based on jeb's post at **[progress % within same line without cls](http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=1344)**.

```
@echo off
cls
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
call :BL.String.CreateCR

<nul set /p "=Hello world!CR!"
REM I will delay here so we can see it work.  You will do other processing
ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 > nul
<nul set /p "=Pie is good"
ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 > nul
echo.
pause
exit /b

:BL.String.CreateCR
::: CR should  be used only with DelayedExpansion
for /F "usebackq" %%a in (`copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul`) DO (
   set "cr=%%a"
)
exit /b
```

Answer (score 1):

You could print a full page.

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO ###############################################################################
ECHO #
ECHO # Hello World
ECHO #
ECHO #
ECHO #
ECHO #
ECHO #
ECHO #
ECHO #
ECHO #
ECHO #
ECHO #
ECHO #
ECHO #
ECHO #
ECHO #
ECHO #
ECHO #
ECHO #
ECHO #
ECHO #
ECHO #
ECHO ###############################################################################
PAUSE
ECHO ###############################################################################
ECHO #
ECHO # Pie is Good
ECHO #
ECHO #
ECHO #
ECHO #
ECHO #
ECHO #
ECHO #
ECHO #
ECHO #
ECHO #
ECHO #
ECHO #
ECHO #
ECHO #
ECHO #
ECHO #
ECHO #
ECHO #
ECHO #
ECHO #
ECHO ###############################################################################
PAUSE
```

Comment: Interesting idea but not what I'm looking for.

Comment: You could use a solution found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978548/windows-console-width-in-environment-variable) to make it more intricate.