# Echo a long string with specified start column for new lines

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, echo

I am writing a small console application. This app should print a help when -h is passed. This is what I'm trying to get:

```
Program that prints help.
Usage:
  prg [OPTIONS]

Options:
  -h - print help.
  -x - some very very very very very very very very very very very very very very
       very very very very long parameter description.
  -y - another  very very very very very very very very very very very very very
       very very very very long parameter description.
```

I'm using `echo.      -x - {long description here}` to print parameter description. And of course when the string is too long it is printed like this:

```
           -x - some very very very very very very very very very very very very
very very very very long parameter description.
```

So the question is how can I print a long string with something like left border specified?

Comment: Do you know the number of columns available for displaying your string?

Comment: No, I don't. That's why I'm asking the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
for /f %%I in ('powershell ^(Get-Host^).UI.RawUI.WindowSize.width') do set width=%%I
SET "spaces= "
:splp
IF "!spaces:~%width%!"=="" SET spaces=%spaces%%spaces%&GOTO splp

CALL :display 0 "Program that prints help."
CALL :display 0 "Usage:"
CALL :display 2 "prg [OPTIONS]"
CALL :display 0
CALL :display 0 "Options:"
CALL :display 2 "-x" 5 "- some very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long parameter description."
CALL :display 2 "-y" 5 "- another  very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long parameter description."

GOTO :EOF

:display
SET "remainder="
SET "line=!spaces:~0,%1!"
IF "%~2"=="" GOTO write
IF "%3"=="" SET "line=%line%%~2"&GOTO write
SET /a indent=%1+%3
SET "remainder=%~2%spaces%"
SET "line=%line%!remainder:~0,%3!
SET "remainder=%~4"
:remainlp
SET /a eol=width-indent-1
:seteollp
SET "eolchar=!remainder:~%eol%,1!"
IF NOT DEFINED eolchar SET "line=%line%%remainder%"&set "remainder="&goto write
IF NOT "%eolchar%"==" " set /a eol-=1&GOTO seteollp
SET "line=%line%!remainder:~0,%eol%!
SET /a eol+=1
set "remainder=!remainder:~%eol%!"
:write
ECHO(%line%
IF NOT DEFINED remainder GOTO :EOF
SET "line=!spaces:~0,%indent%!"
GOTO remainlp
```

I'll claim no originality for the magic powershell line - it came from [Rojo's response here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978548/windows-console-width-in-environment-variable)

Comment: Spent about half of an hour to understand how this script works. But this is definitly what I was looking for. The only question I have is is there any requirements for running the powershell string? I mean will it be working on any windows machine?

Comment: AFAIAA, it should work on any machine where powershell can be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using tabs?

For example:

```
echo.^     -x - some very very very very very very very very very very
echo.^  ^   very very very very very very very 
echo.^  ^   very long parameter description.
```

I've used the '`^`' character to show where the tabs are and had to split the message over a few lines to stop the word wrapping.

Here is the script I just tried (option x uses tabs and option y does not)

```
@echo OFF

echo.   Usage:
echo.       prg [OPTIONS]
echo.
echo.   Options:
echo.     -h - print help.
echo.      -x - some very very very very very very very very very very
echo.       very very very very very very very 
echo.       very long parameter description.
echo.      -y - another  very very very very very very very very very very very very very
echo.            very very very very long parameter description.
```

And I get the following output (option x uses tabs and option y does not)

```
C:\Temp>usage.bat
        Usage:
                prg [OPTIONS]

        Options:
          -h - print help.
           -x - some very very very very very very very very very very
                very very very very very very very
                very long parameter description.
           -y - another  very very very very very very very very very very very
very very
                 very very very very long parameter description.
```

Comment: Yes, I use tabs in each `echo` statement. But what if user will use custom window width. Try running your script after `mode con:cols=40`, for example. BTW, I don't think `^` sign is required to escape tab symbol, when `echo.` (with dot) is used.

Comment: Your right it will only really work in a standard 80 column prompt.  I guess you could query the number of columns and display different usage messages accordingly, but that would lead to a lot of repetition.  <br/>  How about forcing the console window to be 80 columns at the start of the script.   <br/>  In my answer I was just using the '^' character to illustrate where I'd put my tabs :)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "textx=some very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long parameter description."

REM find screen widht (subtract 8 for a leading tab and two for a right "border" :
for /f "tokens=2 delims=: " %%i in ('mode^|find "Columns"') do set /a colums=%%i-10

call :wrap "-x" "%textx%"
call :wrap "-y" "another quite quite quite quite quite quite quite quite quite quite quite quite quite quite quite quite quite long parameter description."

exit /b

:wrap <option> <text>
 set "text=%~2"
 set /p ".=%~1"<nul
 for /l %%i in (0,%colums%,1000) do echo.   !text:~%%i,%colums%!|findstr ".."
goto :eof
```

NOTE: there is a  between the `echo.` and `!text....`

You may have to replace `Columns` in `find "Columns"` with the correct string (it's language dependent)

I subtracted `10` from the screen width: 8 for the leading  and two to end the line two chars before the windows ends.

`1000` is the max length of the string. Adapt as needed. (the higher the value, the slower the output)

`|findstr ".."` supresses the output of empty lines

This has a few disadvantages:

there is no space in front of `-x` (`set` does not support it)

It will wrap at the end of the line even if it's in the middle of a word. Doing a "word wrap" could be done, but with a lot more code.

It has problems with special chars (for example `&`, `!`, `|`)