# I want to read a console command into my current Console application from my code

Tags: c#

```
con lines=x
con cols=x
```

These are the console commands that I want to run in my current C# Console application so     that I can expand the console window above the max allowed from the

```
Console.SetWindowSize(x,x);
```

So basically I want to run a console command in my current console application.

Not in a new Process of command line.

I think i had console applications confused with command prompt(cmd)

```
    Console.SetWindowSize(Console.LargestWindowWidth,Console.LargestWindowHeight);
```

This seems like the safest way to get a better size for your application

Comment: Okay, so your question is? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Process.Start("cmd","/C copy c:\\file.txt lpt1");

Comment: I tried to get the current process and do the start method on that

Comment: Simply use `Console.Read` or smth. like that to read in the commands, parse them and execute the proper methods associated with them.

Comment: This seems to do the trick

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. Windows won't let you set the size of the console window larger than the screen. If you try, it will set the console window to the largest allowed size, and set the buffer to the size that you specify. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/4692673/56778 for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Console.ReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.console.readline.aspx) to provide a kind of command prompt and parse the data which the users enters after that. Then you can check if the user entered `con lines` for example and set the window dimensions based on this.