# Access console logs ( cmd.exe using Windows XP)

Tags: windows, cmd

When my application logs lots of lines to the Windows console, the first lines disappear and only the the latest lines are shown. Is it possible to get the first logs anywhere? Are they stored on the system anywhere?

Comment: My crystal ball is cloudy today, you should better post your script now.

Comment: redirect the output to a file with yourapp.exe > logfile.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No.

However, depending on your access and need, you could:

- [Redirect the output](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true) of the application to a file:

  `myapp.exe 1>logfile.txt 2>&1`
- Pipe the output through [more](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/more.mspx), to enable page-by-page viewing of the output:

  `myapp.exe | more`
- Increase the number of buffered (displayed) lines of your console window:

  Open system menu of the command window (CTRL+SPACE) and select **Properties** and increase the **Height** of the **Screen Buffer Size**

  Or programmatically: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4692673/932282)

Comment: thanks for the hint with the Properties, that is exactly what I was searching for