# Error building Qt6 where to find error log?

Tags: c++, qt, ninja

I'm trying to build Qt 6.2 from sources with VS2019 under Win10. I followed the steps described in https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/windows-building.html:

```
> set QTDIR=C:\dev\qt6\qt-everywhere-src-6.2.0
> cd %QTDIR%
> set PATH=%QTDIR%\qtbase\bin;%PATH%
> set PATH=C:\dev\qt6\Python39;%PATH%
> set PATH=C:\dev\qt6\perl\perl\bin;%PATH%
> set PATH=C:\dev\qt6\cmake-3.21.3-windows-x86_64\bin;%PATH%
> configure -debug-and-release
> cmake --build . --parallel
```

It builds form some time and then ends up showing:

```
Remarque : inclusion du fichier :      C:\dev\qt6\qt-everywhere-src-6.2.0\qtbase\include\QtCore/qsize.h
Remarque : inclusion du fichier :      C:\dev\qt6\qt-everywhere-src-6.2.0\qtbase\include\QtCore/qrect.h
Remarque : inclusion du fichier :      C:\dev\qt6\qt-everywhere-src-6.2.0\qtbase\include\QtCore/qxmlstream.h
Remarque : inclusion du fichier :      C:\dev\qt6\qt-everywhere-src-6.2.0\qtbase\include\QtSvg/qtsvgglobal.h
Remarque : inclusion du fichier :    C:\dev\qt6\qt-everywhere-src-6.2.0\qtbase\include\QtSvg\qtsvgversion.h
[3721/15034] Automatic MOC for target Qml
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

That is not very verbose....where should I lookup to get more information about the failure? What subcommand failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building in parallel `Ninja` does not stop output just after an error, so an error description can reside far before the log end.

Besides, if your console window buffer size is small, an error description can be completely re-written by a later output.

So, you can:

1. [Increase console buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692673/how-to-change-screen-buffer-size-in-windows-command-prompt-from-batch-script)
2. Build
3. Search (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) for the string: `FAILED:`

or

1. Redirect the build output to a file
2. Search for the string: `FAILED:`

Comment: Thanks. Finally used `cmake --build . --parallel > compile.txt 2>&1` to get the full log.